# Selenium WebDriver - Process unexpectedly closed

Tags: node.js, firefox, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, geckodriver

I have built a Docker image on top of Node to execute a bunch of Selenium tests.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```html
#Dockerfile for individual node instance

FROM node:latest

#add the .js Selenium testcase files
COPY ./tests /tests

#add geckodriver (latest version) from local directory
COPY geckodriver-v0.19.1-linux64.tar.gz /

#set Path variable to firefox binary
ENV Path="/firefox/firefox-bin"

RUN ["mkdir","/firefox"]

#download firefox executables
RUN ["wget","-O","/firefox/ff.tar.bz2","https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=de"]

#unpack firefox executables
RUN ["tar","xjf", "/firefox/ff.tar.bz2"]

#unpack geckodriver
RUN ["tar", "xzf", "geckodriver-v0.19.1-linux64.tar.gz"]

#install webdriver on node
RUN ["npm","install","selenium-webdriver@3.6.0"]

#launch the test suite
CMD ["node","/tests/suite.js"]
#CMD ["tail","-f","/dev/null"]
```

The code fails by executing the following initilization (the test cases in suite.js call the method init before doing anything):

```html
let obj = {
  driver: null,
  By: null,
  init: function() {
    let webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
        By = webdriver.By,
        until = webdriver.until;
    
    let firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
    //choose binary which was copied to the docker image
    let binary = new firefox.Binary('/firefox/firefox-bin');
    //run in headless mode
    binary.addArguments("-headless");

    let profile = new firefox.Profile();
    //add proxy
    profile.setPreference('network.proxy.type', 1);
    profile.setPreference('network.proxy.http', 'localhost');
    profile.setPreference('network.proxy.http_port', 8090);
    profile.setPreference('network.proxy.no_proxies_on', '');
    
    let options = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile);
    options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE)
    options.setBinary(binary);
    
    obj.driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .setFirefoxOptions(options)
        .build();
    obj.By = webdriver.By;
    return obj;
  }
```

However, the code above runs fine with my local node installation. But when i run the built docker image, it produces the following:

WebDriverError: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 255
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:514:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:519:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js:521:41)
    at createDriver (/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:645:16)
    at Object.init (/tests/upik_lib.js:28:10)
    at Object. (/tests/upik_suite.js:1:97)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)

I really dont have an idea of what went wrong here. I would expect to execute node to launch my selenium tests. I included Geckodriver and a firefox binary. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem these days, apparently it's due to the firefox executables being downloaded directly from the link inside a docker container, which doesn't have a set of libraries firefox needs to work. To solve the problem I therefore had to add the following line to the **Dockerfile**.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget bzip2 libxtst6 packagekit-gtk3-module libx11-xcb-dev libdbus-glib-1-2 libxt6 libpci-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

To test which libraries were missing, I connected to the docker container and try to run firefox in the following way:

```
firefox -headless
```